# Add color to a simple product when importing csv files

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a CSV file with products and a column for colour. I created a Colour attribute in Woocommerce but when I import this CSV file, this attribute does not appear in the "Map to field" list.
I already changed the column's name to "meta:Colour" and cleaned the Cache. I already created Terms for this attribute (Black, Blue, Green, Red, White) and manually picked colours for the first and last product. But it doesn't work and the Colour attribute is not showing up in the "Map to field" list.

The products are not variable.

How do I add this values to my products?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, ensure that you've created the attribute properly in WooCommerce. Make sure the attribute name in WooCommerce matches the CSV column header exactly, including letter case. In your case, it should be "Colour" without any typos.

Also, ensure that the attribute is assigned to the correct product type, which should be "Simple Product" based on your description.

If the issue persists, consider checking if any third-party plugins or custom code might be conflicting with the import process.

Comment: I installed Product Import Export for WooCommerce. It worked. Thank you